# count distinct if a condition is satisfied

Tags: sql, oracle, count, average, distinct

I have a table which shows if a address_no has a telephone or not. To determine, i am looking at cell_phone and house_phone columns and want to write 'no phone' only when house_phone and cell_phone is null.

every address_no has records for the people living at the address. If at least one person has a phone or house_phone is not null then that address_no has phone, otherwise address_no has no phone information.

```
ADDRESS_NO------PERSON_ID------CELL_PHONE-------HOUSE_PHONE
11111-----------11-------------111000----------------------  
11111-----------12-------------122000----------------------
11111-----------13----------------------------------1313000
22222-----------21----------------------------------2121000
33333-----------31-----------------------------------------
33333-----------32-----------------------------------------
44444-----------41-------------411000---------------4141000
55555-----------51-------------511000----------------------
55555-----------52-----------------------------------------
55555-----------53-----------------------------------------
```

As shown above, i want to have a result of 4 addresses out of 5 which have telephone info.

How can i write a sql query to find the number in oracle sql

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please learn [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [how not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) before posting a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation and a `case` expression:

```
select address_id,
       (case when max(cell_phone) is null and max(house_phone) is null
             then 'No Phone' else 'Phone'
        end) as phone_flag
from t
group by address_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list the addresses that have phone information, you can filter the dataset with a `having` clause:

```
select address_no
from mytable
group by address_no
having coalesce(max(cell_phone), max(house_phone)) is not null
```

On the other hand if you want to compute the overal ratio of adresses that have phone information, you can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select avg(case when phone_no is null then 0 else 1 end) ratio
from (
    select coalesce(max(cell_phone), max(house_phone)) phone_no
    from mytable
    group by address_no
) t
```